# Teeth Brushing for Preschoolers

Tags: pre-schooler, brushing-teeth

I have a technical question about tooth brushing.

I'm finding it really difficult to brush the cheek-facing "front" side of the tooth.

I myself can fit the whole toothbrush head between my inner cheek and teeth when brushing that side, but if I try that method with my kids, they say that it hurts.

It might be some combination of having smaller mouths and not knowing how to relax their faces for that part.

I'm already using kid-sized toothbrushes with very small heads.

Has anyone else had this problem before?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your child brush their teeth alone?

Comment: How wide do they open their mouth? The wider you open your mouth, the less room there is between the cheek and the outside face of the teeth to fit a toothbrush in.

Comment: Good point.  I'll keep coaching them to close for that part and hopefully they'll catch on eventually 

Answer (score 2):

It was hard for my son too but after we watched the movie Totoro, I started telling him to smile really wide like the cat bus when I brushed his teeth and that finally made it so much easier to reach those teeth! We do "Totoro" for open big and "cat bus" for open wide sideways, works wonders. Maybe it could help you too..